# How to mask the upper triangle of a covariance matrix in sns.heatmap along with a covariance threshold?

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap, correlation, mask

To mask the covariances below a threshold I can use the following:

```
corr = df.corr(method = 'spearman')
sns.heatmap(corr, cmap = 'RdYlGn_r', mask = (corr <= T))
```

now how can I mask the upper triangle with the correlation threshold condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine both masks using the [logical `or`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html) (`|`).

The example code below supposes you want to remove all correlations for which the absolute value is below some threshold:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(7, 10), columns=[*'abcdefghij'])
corr = df.corr(method='spearman')
trimask = np.triu(np.ones_like(corr, dtype=bool))
sns.heatmap(corr, cmap='RdYlGn_r', mask=trimask | (np.abs(corr) <= 0.4), annot=True)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: triangular heatmap with mask]

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

```py
import numpy as np

matrix = diamonds.corr()

mask = np.zeros_like(matrix)

mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize(6,6,))

sns.heatmap(matrix,center = 0, fmt = ".3f", square = True, annot= True, Linewidth = .3, mask=mask);
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: OP didn't ask this, and your solution doesn't provide the **threshold** condition.